# Creating and calling helper / reusable functions

Tags: javascript

Here is my code, simply I am retrieving an array from the back end, and displaying in a select element, and just checking if an attribute is true then I show an input of expiry date, else I hide it
this is working code...all I need to do is just simplify, just need to create 2 helper/ reusable functions so I can call them ... because as you can see, there is repetitive code...

I tried splitting them to two functions, one to search if this item actually exists and if so it returns the item, if not it returns false...and the other will check if that item actually expires and if it does, it shows the form input of expiry date, else it hides it

any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#expiryDate_input').hide();

       var allItems = {!! json_encode($items->toArray()) !!};

       var arrayItemId = $('#item').val();
        
        for (i=0; i < allItems.length; i++) { 
       
       var selectedItemid = allItems[i].id; 
       
       if (selectedItemid == arrayItemId){

                if(allItems[i].expires) {
                 $('#expiryDate_input').show();
             }   
             else {
                 $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
             }
         } 

    }
        

       $("#item").change(function() {

         var currentItemId = $(this).val();

         if (currentItemId == '') {
            $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
         }

         for (i=0; i < allItems.length; i++)   {

             var arrayItemId = allItems[i].id;

             if (currentItemId == arrayItemId){

                if(allItems[i].expires) {
                 $('#expiryDate_input').show();
             }   
             else {
                 $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
             }

         } 

     }        

 });

   });
```

```js
function search(id) {

      for (i=0; i < allItems.length; i++)   {

       var arrayItemId = allItems[i].id;

       if (currentItemId == arrayItemId){

       } return allItems[i];

       else { return false

       }             


   }

}
```

```js
function showHide(item) {

if(item.expires) {
           $('#expiryDate_input').show();
       }   
       else {
           $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
       }

   } 


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function showHide(item) {
        if(item.expires) {
           $('#expiryDate_input').show();
        }   
        else {
           $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
        }
    }
    function search(id) {
        for (i=0; i < allItems.length; i++)   {
            var arrayItemId = allItems[i].id;
            if (id == arrayItemId){
                showHide( allItems[i]);
            }         
        }
    }
    $('#expiryDate_input').hide();

        var allItems = {!! json_encode($items->toArray()) !!};
        var arrayItemId = $('#item').val();
        search(arrayItemId);
    }

    $("#item").change(function() {

        var currentItemId = $(this).val();
        if (currentItemId == '') {
            $('#expiryDate_input').hide();
        }
        search(currentItemId);
    });
});
```